# Graph the set of points $p$ in the plane for which $|p|+|p-A|=6$.

Tags: calculus, geometry

Let $A$ = $(4,2)$. Graph the set of points $p$ in the plane for which

$|p|+|p-A|=6$.

So, what I've done so far is set $p=(x,y)$.

Then I get $\sqrt {x^2 + y^2} = 6 - \sqrt {(x-4)^2 + (y-2)^2}$.

Squaring both sides, I eventually get that $(x-4)^2 + (y-2)^2 = 6 - \sqrt{20}$, but this gives me the equation for a circle, whereas I'm supposed to get an ellipse according to the answer manual. I'd like to know where I'm going wrong, or how to go about the problem correctly.

Comment: `Squaring both sides, I eventually get ...` Recheck your calculations. Even better, post them.

Comment: Once you’ve done the algebra correctly, how do you tell that the equation you end up with represents an ellipse?

Comment: well using $b^{2} -4ac$, I get a negative number, and from what I've read online, that means that it's either a circle or an ellipse. Also, I transformed the conic equation to take into account the rotated axes, and I completed the square, to which I figured that the relation is an ellipse

Comment: I believe that figuring out whether I get an ellipse from $b^2 - 4ac$ may be incorrect, but from several sources online If the $x^2$ and $y^2$ terms are both non-zero and have the same sign (+ or - ), then the conic is an ellipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ellipse is "the set of all points in a plane such that the sum of the distances from two fixed points (foci) is constant". [1](https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m116/conics/conics.html)

$$|p| + |p - (4,2)| = |p - (0, 0)| + |p - (4,2)| = 6$$

Therefore, the graph of the points $p$ is an ellipse with foci $(0, 0)$ and $(4, 2)$.

Comment: Your answer is definitely correct, but it appears that the OP doesn't use this definition of ellipse; otherwise, the answer should be immediate.  But then, I don't know which definition of ellipse the OP is using.

Comment: @Batominovski: Which different definitions are out there for an ellipse?

Comment: @K.M p is the set of all points such that sum of its distances from (0, 0) and (4, 2) is 6 (constant). What is not making sense here?

Comment: @K.M  There is an algebraic definition (i.e., an ellipse is an irreducible quadratic curve in the real projective plane $\mathbb{RP}^2$ with negative discriminant).  There is also a definition due to projective geomery (i.e., an ellipse is an image of a circle projected from a point not in the same plane as the circle such that the image is connected and compact).  The one TenaliRaman uses is the most widely used definition.

Answer (score 0):

Solve $$\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} + \sqrt{(x - 4)^2 + ( y - 2)^2} = 6$$ for $y$ and find:

$$y = \frac{1}{4} \left(\pm 3 \sqrt{-x^2+4 x+4}+x+2\right)$$

[image]

Comment: That does not show it's an ellipse.

Comment: @martycohen:  *What* doesn't show an ellipse?

Comment: Your equation for y.

Comment: This is the equation I entered into *Mathematica* for plotting.

Answer (score 0):

We rotate the $x$-axis and the $y$-axis by angle $\text{arctan}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$, and obtain a new set of orthogonal coordinate axes as follows.  Let $$u:=\frac{2x+y}{\sqrt{5}}\text{ and }v:=\frac{2y-x}{\sqrt{5}}\,.$$  Thus, in the $(u,v)$-system, the coordinates of $A$ are given by
$$(u,v)=\left(2\sqrt{5},0\right)\,.$$
The equation $|P|+|P-A|=6$ for $P\in\mathbb{R}^2$ can be expressed in the $(u,v)$-coordinates as
$$\sqrt{u^2+v^2}+\sqrt{\left(u-2\sqrt{5}\right)^2+v^2}=6\,.$$ 
That is,
$$\left(u-2\sqrt{5}\right)^2+v^2=36-12\,\sqrt{u^2+v^2}+\left(u^2+v^2\right)\,.$$
That is,
$$3\,\sqrt{u^2+v^2}=\sqrt{5}\,u+4$$
or
$$9\,\left(u^2+v^2\right)=5\,u^2+8\sqrt{5}\,u+16\,.$$
That is,
$$4\,\left(u-\sqrt{5}\right)^2+9\,v^2=36\,,$$
or equivalently,
$$\left(\frac{u-\sqrt{5}}{3}\right)+\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)^2=1\,.\tag{*}$$
This is an ellipse centered at $(u,v)=\left(\sqrt{5},0\right)$, or $(x,y)=(2,1)$, with semimajor axis length $3$ and semiminor axis length $2$.  The major axis of the ellipse is parallel to the $v$-axis (i.e., the line $2y=x$ in the $(x,y)$-coordinate system).  The foci of this ellipse are precisely the point $(u,v)=\left(2\sqrt{5},0\right)$ (or $(x,y)=(4,2)$) and the point $(u,v)=(0,0)$ (or $(x,y)=(0,0)$).

---

Indeed, all solutions $(u,v)$ to (*) are given by $u=\sqrt{5}+3\,\cos(t)$ and $v=2\,\sin(t)$ for some $t\in\mathbb{R}$.  Then,
$$u^2+v^2=9+6\sqrt{5}\,\cos(t)+5\,\cos^2(t)=\big(3+\sqrt{5}\,\cos(t)\big)^2$$
and
$$\left(u-2\sqrt{5}\right)^2+v^2=9-6\sqrt{6}\,\cos(t)+5\,\cos^2(t)=\big(3-\sqrt{5}\,\cos(t)\big)^2\,.$$
Thus, if $P$ is given by the $(u,v)$-coordinates satisfying (*), then
$$|P|+|P-A|=\big(3+\sqrt{5}\,\cos(t)\big)+\big(3-\sqrt{5}\,\cos(t)\big)=6\,,$$
so the solution set of $|P|+|P-A|=6$ is precisely the ellipse (*).

Comment: Where do you get $\text{arctan}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$ from?

Comment: The line connecting the foci  $(0,0)$ and $(4,2)$ in $(x,y)$-coordinates makes the angle $\text{arctan}\left(\dfrac12\right)$ to the $x$-axis.

Comment: So, I see why the coordinates of $A$ are given by $(2\sqrt{5},0)$ in the new system, but why do you define $u$ and $v$ the way that you do in the third line?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes